node-sass folder error while installing npm
I am trying to install npm in my local .net project folder using cmd command c:\projectPath\project.Web>npm install but it is ending with lot of warnings and errors. first error says
npm error code 1
npm error path C:\projectPath\project.Web\node_modules\gulp-sass\node_modules\node-sass
npm error command failed

Also:
npm error gyp ERR! node -v v22.9.0
npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
npm error gyp ERR! not ok
npm error Build failed with error code: 1

I have installed nodejs v22.9.0
gulp versions:
CLI version: 3.0.0
Local version: 5.0.0
How should I resolve these errors?
